# Unable to use press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherCoordinate: XCUICoordinate) method with SmartXCUICoordinate

Tags: swift3, ios-simulator, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation

This is related to [Unable to tap (x,y) coordinate in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558447/unable-to-tap-x-y-coordinate-in-landscape-mode). I'm having difficulties controlling the coordinates in my UI tests with a landscape oriented simulator.

I've implemented the SmartXCUICoordinate for my UI tests. The tap() and press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval) methods work well.

I was wondering if someone has found a workaround for the method:

press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherCoordinate: XCUICoordinate)

I haven't able to get away with wrapping this method since it takes in a XCUICoordinate rather than a SmartXCUICoordinate. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: When I use xcuiCoordinate.press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherCoordinate: XCUICoordinate) method the ui test just locks up for me. I can't get this to work

Comment: Maggie, Casale, could you make your question more concise for this issue though?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons Currently when you try and use XCUICoordinate methods on a horizontal simulator, the coordinates are inverted. I've found a workaround that uses a custom class SmartXCUICoordinate, and you're able to wrap the XCUICoordinate methods like tap() and press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval). I'd like to use the method press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherCoordinate: XCUICoordinate) method, but cannot find a workaround for it since it takes in a XCUICoordinate and lock up when you try to use it. I'm wondering if someone else has  found a workarond.